# How to check if a Java thread terminated with exception?

Tags: java, multithreading

Given a thread that has finished doing some work (its status is Thread.State.TERMINATED), is there a way to understand if the thread has completed the Thread.run()/Runnable.run() method correctly or has thrown an uncaught throwable ?

Afaik, a thread goes into the TERMINATED state both when exiting normally and when throwing throwables.

Somebody suggested using an UncaughtExceptionHandler. Given that a thread can have only one UncaughtExceptionHandler (other than the default for all threads), and that the thread code can change the provided one, is it a good practice using them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are interested in could be accomplished using a `Callable` that wraps it run method in a try { } catch block and returns the `Exception` within the Future object it it encountered a problem

Comment: I think this is the right way to handle the problem, at least in my case, where the secondary threads are created and started by another managed thread. Relying on an UncaughtExceptionHandler, considering that only one object can be declared as handler, is not a good option in this context.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)?

This lets you trap uncaufht exceptions if you have a handle on the thread?

Answer (score 4):

You could install an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) or set the [default UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) and have it save the exception that the thread exited with.

Comment: This approach is really interesting, but I have noticed that the code run by the thread overrides the handler provided by me.

Comment: You could hack it to wait until that thread has set the handler, then add your own handler (and still chain any exceptions to their handler)   But that is a pretty bad hack. 

If you have access to where the Thread is started, then you could wrap the submitted Runnable in another Runnable that records the exception and then rethrows it.  (similar to what ControlAltDel suggests below)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to directly do it, but you could surround all your code in the run method with a try/catch statement. If you create a boolean and set it to true when it terminates with a exception then you can you can check the state and if the boolean is true it terminated with an exception and if the boolean is false then it closed correctly.
There is probably a better way but this should work.